# Use PyPDF2 to detect non-embedded fonts in PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, fonts, pypdf

I was hoping someone could help me write a Python function to detect any fonts in the file which are not embedded in the file. I've attempted to use the script linked [here](https://reachtim.com/articles/PDF-Testing.html#test-for-embedded-fonts), and it can detect the documents fonts, but it does not detect fonts which are embedded. I've pasted the script below for convenience:

```py
import sys
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

fontkeys = set(["/FontFile", "/FontFile2", "/FontFile3"])


def walk(obj, fnt, emb):
    if "/BaseFont" in obj:
        fnt.add(obj["/BaseFont"])

    elif "/FontName" in obj and fontkeys.intersection(set(obj)):
        emb.add(obj["/FontName"])

    for k in obj:
        if hasattr(obj[k], "keys"):
            walk(obj[k], fnt, emb)

    return fnt, emb


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_name = sys.argv[1]
    reader = PdfFileReader(file_name)
    fonts = set()
    embedded = set()

    for page in reader.pages:
        obj = page.getObject()
        f, e = walk(obj["/Resources"], fonts, embedded)
        fonts = fonts.union(f)
        embedded = embedded.union(e)

    unembedded = fonts - embedded
    print("Font List")
    print(sorted(list(fonts)))
    if unembedded:
        print("\nUnembedded Fonts")
        print(unembedded)
```

For example, I've downloaded a PDF from Google Docs (type some stuff, save as PDF) with the Arial font, and Adobe Reader has confirmed that the font is embedded. However, the script returns ['/ArialMT'] as a font, and an empty set for embedded fonts. Additionally, it does not look like any of the recursive objects have the keys `{'/FontFile', '/FontFile2', '/FontFile3'}`. I've tried it on other PDFs and it works, so it must be something weird with the Google Docs PDFs. Let me know what other debug information I can give for this PDF file.

[image: Adobe confirming that the font is embedded]

One thing I thought was that it was possible that Google Docs was only embedding fonts which were not in the 14 standard PDF fonts. However, i tried it with a weird font (pacifico), and the script also stated this font was not embedded, when Adobe claims it is.
[image: Pacifico being embedded, script saying its not]

I tried it with [this PDF](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/73229/Base%2014%20Fonts.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), and the script correctly stated that these 14 fonts were embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this script does not handle lists. For example in the Google Docs example, in the PDF object, you see this structure:

```
{'/Encoding': '/Identity-H', '/Type': '/Font', '/BaseFont': '/Pacifico-Regular', '/ToUnicode': IndirectObject(9, 0), '/DescendantFonts': [IndirectObject(16, 0)], '/Subtype': '/Type0'}
```

The key `DescendantFonts` maps to a list of values, which if you recurse deeper into will contain the keys for font files. You have to modify the script to test for arrays as well, for example:

```
if type(obj) == PyPDF2.generic.ArrayObject:  # You can also do ducktyping here
    for i in obj:
        if hasattr(i, 'keys'):
            walk(i, all_fonts, embedded_fonts)
```

Answer (score 1):

It was not obvious where to put the ArrayCheck, as well as needing to check for IndirectObject's as well.  I also removed the unnecessary unions, as the sets are being mutated in place.  Here is complete working code:

```
import PyPDF2


def walk(obj, fnt, emb):
    """
    If there is a key called 'BaseFont', that is a font that is used in the document.
    If there is a key called 'FontName' and another key in the same dictionary object
    that is called 'FontFilex' (where x is null, 2, or 3), then that fontname is
    embedded.

    We create and add to two sets, fnt = fonts used and emb = fonts embedded.
    """

    if isinstance(obj, PyPDF2.generic.IndirectObject):
        # recurse on indirect objects
        walk(obj.get_object(), fnt, emb)

    if not isinstance(obj, (PyPDF2.generic.DictionaryObject, PyPDF2.generic.ArrayObject)):
        # cannot check non dictionary or array objects for properties
        return

    fontkeys = set(["/FontFile", "/FontFile2", "/FontFile3"])
    if "/BaseFont" in obj:
        fnt.add(obj["/BaseFont"])
    if "/FontName" in obj:
        if [x for x in fontkeys if x in obj]:  # test to see if there is FontFile
            emb.add(obj["/FontName"])

    # recurse on dictionaries
    if isinstance(obj, PyPDF2.generic.DictionaryObject):
        for key in obj.keys():
            walk(obj[key], fnt, emb)

    # recurse on arrays
    elif isinstance(obj, PyPDF2.generic.ArrayObject):
        for i in obj:
            walk(i, fnt, emb)


def get_fonts(pdf):
    """Get all the fonts in the PDF and which are and are not embedded"""
    fonts = set()
    embedded = set()
    for page in pdf.pages:
        obj = page.get_object()
        walk(obj["/Resources"], fonts, embedded)

    unembedded = fonts - embedded
    return fonts, embedded, unembedded
```